# Documenting Boost.Test test cases

Tags: boost, doxygen, boost-test

Is there any way to use documentary comments for test-cases defined using Boost.Test macros ? Can I use Doxygen-styled comments, will they be parsed correctly?

Comment: According the the doxygen [preprocessing documentation](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/preprocessing.html) it should be possible to document these tests with normal doxygen-style comments, but you will probably have to spend a bit of time playing with the `predefined` flag in your configuration file. See the `IUnknown` class example, about halfway down on [this](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/preprocessing.html) page.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to make your test cases so simple, so obvious and so readable that any documentation you write is superfluous.  See the section titled [Test Case Maintenance and Design](http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/boost.test/libs/test/doc/html/test/guide/test_case_design.html) in my [rewrite of the Boost.Test docs](http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/boost.test).

Comment: Yeah, well, this goes without saying, but I think it would be nice to have a list of all test cases attached to the class in test, so the documentation shows that and what is tested.

Comment: This adds an additional maintenance burden that isn't justified IMO.  It's already the case that actual comments diverge from the code.  The trend in software engineering has been to [express ideas directly in code](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rp-direct) instead of relying on comments or additional metadata on the code.